# Is ($ m \le n $ iff $\frac{n}{m}$ is an even integer) reflexive?

Tags: relations, order-theory

On the domain $S = \{2,3,4,6,8,18,24\}$, consider the partial order: $ m \le n $ iff $\frac{n}{m}$ is an even integer.

Is the above relation reflexive and thus a partial order? I don't see how it's reflexive as $\frac{2}{2}=1$ and 1 is odd.

Comment: This relation is not a partial order since it is not reflexive, from your example.

Comment: According to [Wiki](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set) the relation $\leq$ is a strict partial order. (Then the symbol $<$ should be better).

Answer (score 0):

Your example is correct for showing that the relation is not reflexive.  This is sufficient to conclude that the relation is not a partial order.  Your language suggests that being reflexive is sufficient for the relation to be a partial order, which is not true. It needs to be antisymmetric and transitive as well.